# Shown and actual url in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I am working on my CV using moderncv. I would like to add a homepage within the CV, i.e., NOT in the header. So far I have used the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nopagenumbers{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title (optional)}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote (optional)}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{name}
\cventry{}{\homepagesymbol\httplink{www.homepage.com}}{name}{institution}{}{}

\end{document}
```

The point is that I would like to differentiate the actual homepage link from the shown link in the CV. In other words, since the actual link is kind of ugly and pretty long, my idea is to "mask" it with a simple denomination. However, I would like to keep the homepagesymbol provided by the moderncv-class.

Is there a way to do that easily?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\httplink` has an optional argument for the "beautiful" display text:

```
\httplink[www.homepage.com]{www.ugly.com}
```